# Mathematical Prerequisites for PR&ML

Tags: references

Two months from now, more or less, I am going to have a course on ML which the gentleman who is my professor uses the Bishop **PR&ML** book as reference book. Now, the past semester he introduced Jurafsky's book Speech and Language processing as reference but he actually gave all the questions and exercises from the parts that was not in his slides and was in the book. I just went through the Bishop work and saw that I understand nothing from the formula and concepts. My background was English Studies, but my highschool was science and I was good at math. Could you help me plan a reading so that when in mid November he will actually pass his preliminaries and reach the topics in Bishop's text, I can understand it. I started **ISLR** but I thought maybe I am on the wrong track. It was more accessible than PRML to me. For the probability and stats I  will just start Montgomery and Runger *Probability and statistics for engineers* and for the linear algebra *Elementary linear algebra* by Anton. So if anyone here has actually read PRML and knows the level of math needed can you tell me if I am on the right track? I really appreciate any comment and help.

**Duplicate warning**: I cannot really see how my question could be linked with the above indicate one. Mine addresses mathematical prerequisites for ML.

Comment: In the years that this site has been active, variations on this question have been asked hundreds of times. There's a limit to how many questions can be linked as duplicates, but this should help you get started. If you feel these questions do not address your needs, do a search.  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/faq-best-practices-for-searching-cv If you're still stuck after searching, **please [edit] to explicitly state what you want to learn.**

Answer (score 0):

[Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Mathematics_for_Machine_Learning.html?id=pFjPDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) might be the text that you need, although not having done proper courses in math is likely to remain a handicap in a long term. In practical terms, you could also turn to various hands-on guides, which teach you to use pre-packaged solutions like [Introduction to Machine Learning with Python](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_to_Machine_Learning_with_Py.html?id=vbQlDQAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), [Deep Learning with Python](https://Deep%20Learning%20with%20Python) and many other similar titles, which do not require knowing math at all. The point is that there are many different levels in practicing machine learning -  developing new algorithms, statistical analysis, everyday applications, creating more efficient software implementations - all of them requiring rather different levels in math, statistics and programming.

Comment: Past semester Jurafsky's book was very slight in terms of math, but my professor in his exercises heavily relied on math problems directly or indirectly. Now with Bishop's text I am confident he will actually make it a math based ML course. He only dedicates ⅕ of the final grade to the final exam and the rest goes to the weekly exercises. I need to catch up with it  systematically even if I am going to perform loosely in the first couple of weeks.

Comment: As I said I am currently reading Anton and I do enjoy it for its sake. But I do not know if my pace is ok or not. I saw this Mathematics for ML book, but am I good and ready for the math in Bishop text reading it

Comment: In my memory math in Bishop is rather basic calculus and linear algebra - it doesn't require learning some special subjects. What might pose difficulty is your fluency with this basic math, which is usually gained via a lot of exercising, not just by reading a single book. But considering your situation, you will have to struggle on - redoing your undergraduate degree in math, statistics, physics or another similar subject is probably not an option.

Comment: thank you, I think it is the truth, I have to struggle on, however discouraging l it sounded initially. However, I would rather at least struggle on than being defeated.